# how to ignore directory in find by full path

Tags: linux, find, gnu-findutils

I want to write a function that will find files in current directory I'm currently in. The thing is that if I'm in `/home`, I want to find files in `sys`, `dev` and `var` directories (which is in my home folder). But If I'm in root folder I wish them to be stripped. I tried this:

```
find -L . \( -path '/dev' -o -path '/var' -o -path '/sys' \) -prune \
  -o -type f -print \
  -o -type d -print \
  -o -type l -print
```

But its not working. If I set a dot (.) at beginning of every path I want to exclude - it works for root folder, but also excludes such dirs in other directories, which I do not want.

Is there a way to prune by full (global) file path? I tried a `-wholename` option, but It seems not work for me.

Comment: Is the missing whitespace between the `'sys'` and the closing paren real, or an artifact of your post?

Comment: Also, "pathfinding" is completely unrelated to filesystem paths; it refers to artificial intelligence algorithms. Whereas the "find" tag is overloaded, it's actually better than "pathfinding" for this query.

Comment: BTW, since you're writing a function, why not put conditional logic in the function itself?

Comment: `...function that will find files in directory I'm currently in` => are there any limits for maxdepth?

Comment: I'm assuming that by "in" the OP meant "under", though indeed these aren't the same thing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, I missed space before closing parenthesis, now its fixed. Sorry if I was wrong with tag, thx for fixing. I'm not putting condition into function logic because I find its ugly and to be fair - its not what I'm asking in the first place in this question.

Comment: You tagged your question "bash", initially. Putting logic into a shell function is, well, bash. Otherwise, this is pure find, with no shell involvement. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find "$PWD"`, as in `find "$PWD" -path '/dev' -prune -o -print`,  to search in the current directory by absolute path. Absolute path matches will then succeed.

Answer (score 0):

`-path` doesn't consider `/dev` and `./dev` to be the same, even when running in `/`, because `find` performs string comparisons on names when using `-path` -- it doesn't look up inode numbers for comparison or perform normalization.

Now, if you *do* want to do an inode-number-based lookup, you can do that.

Consider:

```
# this relies on GNU stat for --format
listtree() {
  find -L . \( -inode "$(stat --format=%i /dev)" \
            -o -inode "$(stat --format=%i /var)" \
            -o -inode "$(stat --format=%i /sys) \) -prune \
    -o -type f -print \
    -o -type d -print \
    -o -type l -print
}
```

However, be aware that inode numbers can overlap between different filesystems.